# How to abstract over a destructuring in F#

Tags: f#, abstraction, destructuring

I have some code repetition that I really want to get rid of -

```
// here's some lib code the repetitive code relies on...

module Option

let definitize opts = List.choose id opts

// here's the start of another file...

module Ast

type Expr =
| Violation of Expr
| Boolean of bool
| String of string

// here's the repetitive code...

let exprToOptViolation expr = match expr with | Violation v -> Some v | _ -> None
let exprToOptBoolean expr = match expr with | Boolean b -> Some b | _ -> None
let exprToOptStr expr = match expr with | String n -> Some n | _ -> None

let exprsToOptViolationStrs exprs = List.map exprToOptViolation exprs
let exprsToOptBools exprs = List.map exprToOptBoolean exprs
let exprsToOptStrs exprs = List.map exprToOptStr exprs

let exprsToViolationStrs exprs =
    let optViolationStrs = exprsToOptViolationStrs exprs
    let violationStrs = Option.definitize optViolationStrs
    (optViolationStrs, violationStrs)    

let exprsToBools exprs =
    let optBools = exprsToOptBools exprs
    let bools = Option.definitize optBools
    (optBools, bools)

let exprsToStrs exprs =
    let optStrs = exprsToOptStrs exprs
    let strs = Option.definitize optStrs
    (optStrs, strs)
```

As you can see, it is the same algorithm repeated 3 times. However, I don't know how to generalize code that requires passing a destructuring facility like `match expr with | destructureFn a -> Some a | _ -> None`. Can someone help? I've actually got 5 repetitions in my code (and growing) that need to get factored down.

Cheers!

*** CONCLUSION ***

Using desco's answer, I've reached this refactoring -

```
let exprsToValues exprToOptValue exprs =
    let optValues = List.map exprToOptValue exprs
    let values = Option.definitize optValues
    (optValues, values)

let exprsToViolationStrs exprs = exprsToValues (fun expr -> match expr with | Violation v -> Some v | _ -> None) exprs
let exprsToBools exprs = exprsToValues (fun expr -> match expr with | Boolean b -> Some b | _ -> None) exprs
let exprsToStrs exprs = exprsToValues (fun expr -> match expr with | String s -> Some s | _ -> None) exprs
```

Thanks desco!

Comment: Done. Please let me know if the assumptions of the below answer still hold.

Comment: desco's solution will work. You can omit `definitize` and use `List.choose id` instead.

Comment: Decided to use definitize as defined by `let definitize opts = List.choose id opts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is pretty complicated to reason without seeing actual code, probably something like this will work

```
type E = | Violation of string | Boolean of bool | String of string
module Option = 
    let definitize vOpt = vOpt |> List.map (function Some x -> sprintf "%A" x | _ -> "none")

let mkEToViolationsStr f exprs = 
    let optViolationStrs = List.map f exprs
    let violationStrs = Option.definitize optViolationStrs
    (optViolationStrs, violationStrs)    

let exprsToViolationStrs2 = mkEToViolationsStr (function Violation v -> Some v | _ -> None)
let exprsToBools2 = mkEToViolationsStr (function Boolean b -> Some b | _ -> None)
let exprsToStrs2 = mkEToViolationsStr (function String s -> Some s | _ -> None)
```

Comment: Yep. You beat me to it. The key is passing the destructuring function to do a map.

Comment: I don't know if this affects your answer, but the only assumption you have wrong in the definition of definitize. It's - `let definitize opts = let somes = List.filter Option.isSome opts in List.map (fun (opt : 'a option) -> opt.Value) somes`

Comment: @BryanEdds: Your definition of `definitize` is equivalent to `List.choose`.

Comment: Instead of inlining List.choose, I reimplemented definitize as `let definitize opts = List.choose id opts`. I think hiding the use of the id function in List.choose under a function gives us a nice new semantic.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but `optValues` in

```
let optValues = List.map exprToOptValue exprs
```

seems to be unnecessary. It will return `Expr option`, `string option` or `bool option` in each case, which makes it more difficult to use. Either you keep `exprs` and return it to do some calculation later:

```
let exprsToValues exprToOptValue exprs =
    let values = List.choose exprToOptValue exprs
    (exprs, values)
```

or simply returns `values` only. In the latter case, meanings of `exprsToSomething` functions totally fit to their names:

```
let exprsToViolationStrs exprs = List.choose (function | Violation v -> Some v | _ -> None) exprs
let exprsToBools exprs = List.choose (function | Boolean b -> Some b | _ -> None) exprs
let exprsToStrs exprs = List.choose (function | String s -> Some s | _ -> None) exprs
```

Comment: Yes, this is even better once I rework the code a bit. I was definitely caught in some sloppy thinking here. Thanks!